# Per identity roles in cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I have a `cognito identity pool`, I would like to set up a policy that allows authenticated users to publish and subscribe to topics associated with their devices in IoT core. However since authenticated users all have the same policy, how can I edit policies on a per user basis to only allow their `cognito` identity to access particular user specific resources i.e. not all of `IoT core` just `IoT core` related to the user.